# How to set the source path in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am embedding Ace locally offline and so am not using the hosted package and am subject to the same origin policy.
How do you tell ace to look in a particular folder for it's source of modes, themes and workers?

You used to be able to use:

```
editor.config.set("modePath", "Scripts/Ace");
editor.config.set("workerPath", "Scripts/Ace");
editor.config.set("themePath", "Scripts/Ace");
```

But that doesn't work in the latest version.
How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue and you can actually let Ace know what's the base folder path this way:
`ace.config.set("basePath", "/Scripts/Ace");`

This work with the latest version I have, v1.1.3

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar requirement in a current project of mine.

I created an Angular project with all the files bundles in a single directory without access to `node_modules` in runtime, using a remote package for the ace `basePath` was out of the question.

Then I stumbled upon the Ace embedding guide and it clued me that I can import the relevant modes and themes straight from my dependencies and just use `new` instead of a path string.

https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-api-docs/index.html#embedding-ace

from the docs:

```js
var JavaScriptMode = ace.require("ace/mode/javascript").Mode;
editor.session.setMode(new JavaScriptMode());
```

So I just imported the mode and theme I went and provided them straight to Ace

```js
import DraculaTheme from "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-dracula";
import JavaScriptMode from "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript";

const aceEditor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);
aceEditor.session.setValue("function greet() {\n\tconsole.log('hello world');\n}\n");

aceEditor.setTheme(DraculaTheme);
aceEditor.session.setMode(new JavaScriptMode.Mode());
```

Notice that I didn't set any `basePath` !!!

[image]

Comment: svarog - thank you. your answer saved my day after already wasting 1-2 days on solving this problem.

EDIT: However, if I dont set basePath it throws errors

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to achieve the same thing is to embed all scripts from the Ace source folder into the web page manually, excluding the `worker-xxx.js` files. This is still a bodge though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [@rorofromfrance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115903/4058484) solve my problem of the base folder path on loading [Ace script](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/master/src) on the fly:

```
$.getScript($('#js')[0].href, function() {
    $('.theme').change(function() {draw.change();});
    $.getScript("/ace/src-min/ace.js", function() {
        if (!editor) {ace.config.set("basePath", "/ace/src-min"); draw.editor();};
        $.getScript("/underscore/underscore-min.js", function() {
            editor.getSession().on('change', _.debounce(function() {draw.diagram();}, 100));
            $.getScript("/tensorflow/tf.min.js", function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    url: "/sitemap.xml", 
                    success: draw.getJSON(xml)
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```